# Stripe checkout PAY button change text

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

How to change the text in a stripe checkout modal box from PAY to something else.

I know I can do custom text on the button that pops up the modal.

```
description: 'ADD CARD',
label:'ADD CARD',
```

But on the actual modal window. It still just says PAY on the button.  I want it to say ADD CARD.

Answer (score 18):

With the simple integration also you can do:

```
data-label="Donate"
```

Comment: where exactly do you add this?

Comment: Check the so-called `simple` example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple)

Comment: i am using stripe through a plugin in woocommerce.I cant seem to understand where i have to add that code .If you can help that would be great

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with woocommerce. I have used it only with vanilla js by following the examples stripe shares in the docs. I suppose your plugin should allow you to add some attributes on your own to override the default setup, right?

Comment: Funny thing is that i did translate it through a relevant .php file and it didnt translate,also through loco translate but still it remains as it is.Well thanks for your time. φιλε μου .If anyone can contribute it would be higly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

You can customize that with the `data-panel-label` or `panelLabel` option: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional

Comment: data-panel-label not works for me . But panelLabel works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Staying at the [Stripe Checkout Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional), is only possible to edit the `label` attribute when using the Simple integration (via the `data-*` attributes).

**EDIT**

With the Custom integration is possible to set the button text in the `panelLabel` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use label as a property within StripeCheckout

Example:

```
<StripeCheckout label="Your text here" />
```